# Building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, gsl, textmate2

I would like to use the GNU Scientific Library (GSL) while continuing to use the TextMate text editor but I had some compile issues when I compile the code in TextMate.

First of all, I use an M1 Mac (Ventura 13.0.1) and the GSL library is installed in : /usr/local/include/gsl

For trying the compilation, I took the most basic example and I compiled it with a very generic MakeFile.

**Code :**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h>

int
main (void)
{
  double x = 5.0;
  double y = gsl_sf_bessel_J0 (x);
  printf ("J0(%g) = %.18e\n", x, y);
  return 0;
}
```

**MakeFile :**

```
CC = gcc
EXEC = PROG
SRC = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)
CFLAGS = -g -Wall

LIBS = -lm -lgsl -lgslcblas -I/usr/local/include/gsl
RM = rm -rf


all : $(EXEC)

%.o : %.c 
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $<
    
$(EXEC) : $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS) && time ./$(EXEC) && make clean


.PHONY : clean

clean :
    rm -rf $(EXEC) && rm -rf *.o
```

Thankfully, if I compile with the macOS terminal, everything is OK. I also tried to compile my code in VS Code with the in-app Terminal and it works fine.

However, I am having some errors when trying to compile my program with TextMate using the MakeFile Bundle (see below). After hours of reading and trying to figure it out, I think the problem is that the compiler of TextMate is not the same as the macOS compiler and it works fine on the macOS terminal thanks to Rosetta. I'm not a specialist at all so I'm very not sure of what I say.

Here is the **error code** :

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libgslcblas.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64

...

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

...

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [PROG] Error 1
```

I also tried to install the library via Homebrew and change the PATH in the MakeFile but, in TextMate, I had the same error message.

The reason why I post here is that I could not find any solution for the TextMate Editor and because it works properly with the native Terminal from macOS.

So, is there a way to fix this issue in TextMate (maybe in the MakeFile ? in the TextMate app directly ?) ? Again, I'm not a specialist and I really don't know how to fix this...

EDIT : I tried to reinstall the library by compiling the file using the following command :

```
./configure CC ="gcc -arch x86_64"
./make
...
```

And now, it works on TextMate but not on the macOS Terminal anymore... And I have, in the macOS terminal :

```
ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libgsl.dylib, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
...
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
```

Which is the exact opposite of what I had before. Is there a way to compile the library in such a way that I can compile my program in both?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found a solution that works for me.

For this to work, when you install the library via the `./configure` of the GSL package, you will have to precise multiple architectures and then the command to type in the terminal should be :

`sudo ./configure CC="gcc -arch arm64 -arch x86_64"`

By doing this, you should be able to compile your program in any IDE with the appropriate MakeFile that I wrote above because the library was built for several architectures.